# SQL :: Many to Many tables or just Foreign Keys

Tags: sql

I'm building an app and I can't get my head around some basic concepts.

The story I'm building around is that USERS can create MESSAGES about PRODUCTS.

Users will appear only once in the USERS table.
Products will appear only once in the PRODUCTS table.

But Users can create many MESSAGES, each about a single PRODUCT.

So, multiple products will be referenced in MESSAGES.

My question at this point is, are there MANY-TO-MANY relationships between Users->Messages AND Products->Messages?

i.e. should i create linker tables between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this bit is true...

> MESSAGES, each about a single PRODUCT.

...then the cardinality between messages and products is many to one.

So I would expect your message table to contain FKs to  User  and a Product but that's it

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have two one-to-many relationships.

USERS and MESSAGES:
One user can have many messages, and one message is associated with one user.  If this is true, then you have a one-to-many relationship.

PRODUCTS and MESSAGES:
One product can refer to many messages, and one message can have one product.  If this is true, then you have a one-to-many relationship.

There is no direct relationship between USERS and PRODUCTS.

If these statements are true, you won't need any additional linking tables.